# storing data from a loop in a matrix

Tags: r, loops, matrix, storage

I would like to code a loop for cross-validation: computing MSE for a one- and a four-step forecast and store the results in a matrix. The problem I get is that the columns for the 1 to 3-step forecast get overwritten and I get just the 4-step forecast in all columns. Anybody can help?

```
k<-20
n<-length(xy)-1
h<-4
start <- tsp(xy) [1]+k
j <- n-k
mseQ1 <- matrix(NA,j,h)

colnames(mseQ1) <- paste0('h=',1:h)

for(i in 1:j)
{
xtrain <- window(xy, end=start+(i-1))
xvalid <- window(xy, start=start+i, end=start+i)

qualifiedETS <- ets(xtrain, alpha=NULL, beta=NULL, additive.only=TRUE, opt.crit="mse")
fcastHW <- forecast(qualifiedETS, h=h)

mseQ1[i,] <- ((fcastHW[['mean']]-xvalid)^2)
}
```

Comment: You are storing the results to a variable which will take the latest value assigned to it. You need to make `xtrain`,`xvalid`,`qualifiedETS`, `fcastHW` as matrices indexed by `i`, in order to store the values for each of the step per iteration.

Comment: Maybe try to substitute  

`mseQ1 <- matrix(NA,j,h)` with `mseQ1 <- data.table()` 

and then substitute 

`mseQ1[i,] <- ((fcastHW[['mean']]-xvalid)^2)` with 

`tmp <- ((fcastHW[['mean']]-xvalid)^2) 
mseQ1 <- rbind(mseQ1,tmp)`

P.S.: You will need to load `library(data.table)`

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answers, both was helpful and did work!